# Community Profile Selection Issue

Tags: community, self-registration

Trying to create a basic login/self-registration page for a community webpage. Having some issue with linking new user accounts to a profile, as the dropbox has no profile options to select from. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Create a customer community profile and add that profile as member of community

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a profile with a User Licence "**Customer Community Login**" and then you will be able to select that template :)

Then, add the profile to the "**Members**" section to let them access to your community.